# Добрый день, есть программа на pygame нужно, чтобы когда true воспроизводился звук с итервалом 2 секунды

Tags: python, pygame

есть программа на pygame нужно, чтобы когда true воспроизводился звук с итервалом 2 секунды, но есть проблема,

```
s = pygame.mixer.Sound('hp+.wav')
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    s.play()
    sleep(2)
```

у меня вся программа засыпает на 2 секунды, подскажите пожалуйста что делать

Comment: Кроме sleep(2) что-нибудь пробовали?

Comment: нет я больше не нашел

Comment: Можете использовать asyncio, но как по мне это избыточно сложное решение для такой задачи